# Fancy way to pipe / filter certain sequences of events

Tags: rxjs

Let's assume I have an observable that returns random numbers and I only want to get informed about every 2nd (or n-th) occurrence of it, I right now would write following filter:

```
import { interval, of } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

let highValue = false;

interval(100)
  .pipe(
    map((v) => Math.random()),
    tap((v) => console.log(v)),
    filter((v) => {
      if (v > 0.9) {
        if (highValue) {
          highValue = false;
          return true;
        } else {
          highValue = true;
          return false;
        }
      }

      return false;
    })
  )
  .subscribe((v) => {
    console.warn(v);
  });
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test-rs53sg?file=index.ts)

Could anyone suggest a more mature solution?

(I hope that's not too opinion-based, but IMHO it feels like my current solution could be pretty simplified, knowing the right operators.)

Comment: Consider `scan`?

Comment: You mean scan + filter? Sounds like a fancy solution, haven't thought about scan. It passes the last value so no need for a static variable outside my pipe. Could be the best solution!

If you write it down I'd mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scan + Filter + map is a pretty typical solution to this:

```js
interval(200)
  .pipe(
    map(() => Math.random()),
    // compute whether to notify based on previous values
    scan((acc, value) => {
      const isHigh = value > 0.9
      const notify = isHigh && !acc.notify
      return {
        value,
        notify
      }
    }, { notify: false }),
    // filter to just the ones you want to notify on
    filter(({notify}) => notify),
    // transform the data back to the actual value (remove the book-keeping info)
    map(({value}) => value)
  )
  .subscribe(v => console.warn(v))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a single operator to do this a little more nicely. I named it `filterNth` but you can name it whatever you like:

```js
const { filter, interval, map, tap } = rxjs;

const filterNth = (n, predicate = () => true) => (
  (observable) => observable.pipe(
    filter(predicate),
    filter((value, index) => (index + 1) % n === 0),
  )
);

interval(1000).pipe(
  map(Math.random),
  tap((value) => console.log(`tap: ${value}`)),
  filterNth(2, (value) => value > 0.9),
).subscribe((value) => console.log(`subscribe: ${value}`));
```

```css
div.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@7.8.1/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Like your solution pretty much! But an inline scan seams even more comfortable to me. Thank you very much anyway, maybe I'll even go with this solution.